# TypeError: data.getElementsByTagName is not a function while trying to delete using function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to delete an object, when the button is pressed.  I get an error:

> "TypeError: data.getElementsByTagName is not a function".

In my code I'm trying to combine php and javascript to achieve desired result.  It works in php when I type:

```
$retval .= this->Shoptobedestroyed->destroy();
```

now I'm trying to make it with an event - e.g. with a button in javascript.  In other words I want the button click event to add text "this->Shoptobedestroyed->destroy();" to variable $retval, which is a php variable.

Please let me know how to fix the code or explain what this error means so I can investigate on my own.

```
$retval .= "<button id=\"btn\" onclick=\"delshop()\">Delete</button>";
            $retval .= "
            <script>
            function delshop()
            {
                this->Shoptobedestroyed->destroy();
            }
            </script>
            ";
```

Comment: Methods in javascript are accessed via dot notation, not arrow.  So `this.Shoptobedestroyed.destroy()`.  Also, `this` will be a reference to the window object, which is probably not what you want.  However there is nothing that you've posted which indicates what `data` is so it's not possible to answer the question as is, add more code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  What I'm trying to do is to combine php and javascript code to achieve the result of deleting an object.  I'll edit my post to show more code.

Comment: Your php variables and objects live on the server and are only alive during a HTTP request.  Much later, when someone clicks that button, the connection to that server has ended, so there is no way for javascript to trigger a php function (or any kind of server-side function) directly.  You will need to send another HTTP request specifically crafted to run, in your case, the delshop function, which is where AJAX is useful.

Comment: Yes I understand that php is serverside.  How can I send another HTTP request to run the delshop function with AJAX?